# apache-webserver-website publishing

Tags: apache

i want to do the following:
1.  Set up of Apache
2.  Use CGI to communicate between a form and database
3.  Use Server Side Includes
4.  Access a data base
5.  Use a virtual site
6.  Generate a Web page dynamically based on some kind of server-side processing.
Implement some form of sever security

any help appreciated? thanks in advance. i am a newbie and working on the above assignment. please help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start by downloading [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) and reading their documentation.

If you need to work with a  database then you need to download and install one. [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) would be a good choice.

Here is a good resource for starting to work with [CGI](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/).

It sounds like this is a school assignment so you may want to check to see if they have this already set up for you. It will save you a lot of time and headaches.

You also can use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) which has Apache, MySQL, and a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out XAMPP or something similar.  XAMPP is a development environment that includes apache, mysql, and php, and it makes the configuration part simple allowing you more time to get working on your database and scripts.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Good luck.